# jQuery ajax double call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem with jquery(ajax), I have this function:

```
page: function(p, cont) {

    cont = typeof cont !== 'undefined' ? cont : this;

    $.ajax({
        url: p,
        timeout: 10000,
        complete: function() {...}
    }).done(function(html) {
        $(cont).append(html);
    });

}
```

When I use this function in html (onClick), every time when i click on button request repeats, how to prevent that? I want to load content only one time.

*Note: this function was used by several buttons not only one.*

Thanks!

Comment: How are you binding your click handler? You could try binding it with `$.one`

Comment: Instead of doing html(onClick) why don't you use a built in jQuery function to recognise when the buttons are being clicked?

Comment: `cont` will never be undefined in that context, unless you explicitly pass the variable as undefined.

Comment: Either http://api.jquery.com/click/ or http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @m1ket - .live() is deprecated, its .on() now. .click() is shorthand for .on('click').

Comment: Show your code for calling this.

Comment: @BradM I think that is the point. He is making it an option parameter. If they don't pass it in, it will be undefined. If it is left out, it just chooses `this`. This is probably because most of the time `this` is used, but there are reasons to want to use something different.

Comment: i don't want to create $('#bla').click... for 1000 buttons, i want to make ajax request from onClick

Comment: call ex. <a href="#pt2" onClick="Ajax.page('http://example.com/bla/', '#pt2');">Something</a>

Comment: @JeffShaver Thanks for pointing out that javascript parameters may be optional by default, I never even considered doing that (I just stick to passing `null`, which I feel makes intention more clear).

Comment: @BradM it is definitely more intentional and clear. Just don't wanna type the extra `, null` over and over probably. But I agree that passing in null is more clear

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use a variable on global scope as a "blocker", like:

```
var blocker = false;

page: function(p, cont) {
    if(!blocker){
        blocker = true;
    }else{
        return;
    }
    cont = typeof cont !== 'undefined' ? cont : this;   
    $.ajax({
        url: p,
        timeout:10000,
        complete: function() { ... }
        }).done(function(html) {
            $(cont).append(html);
    });

}
```